# Why do I get a 403 error with the Udemy API?

Tags: php, curl

A couple of days ago, the code below stopped returning results from the Udemy API, and I can't figure out why. Now It's returning a 403 error.

My client ID and client secret keys are still working fine returning 200 when testing them on the Udemy site: https://www.udemy.com/developers/affiliate/methods/get-courses-list/

It worked fine for about two months after the launch.

```
    $url = 'https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/?search=java';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

//HTTP username.
$clientID = 'XXXXX';
//HTTP password.
$clientSecret = 'XXXXX';
//Create the headers array.
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("$clientID:$clientSecret")
);
//Set the headers that we want our cURL client to use.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
   // echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
   // echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($result, true);
    
    print_r($json);
```

Comment: Can you share more details, like the full and exact error message?

Comment: Improve your Question! Could you give examples with a description of the codes, for your question? This practice will considerably improve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I only have a 403 error. I've added if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($ch); below $result=curl_exec($ch);} but it doesn't display any error. The description of the code is in my question, there is no more code, I'm not sure what else to add, please let me know. It was working for about two months and suddenly stopped. My API keys are still valid (tested on the Udemy site). How can I get a full error message? Thanks.

Comment: _“How can I get a full error message?”_ - have you checked what `$result` actually contains?

Comment: Got error code: 1020. It seems that my request is blocked. But my Status is Approved, in the Udemy account :/

Comment: Right, got a reply from Udemy: Thanks for contacting. Unfortunately, Udemy's own API is no longer supported internally, so you can not use it. 
We do have an API that's hosted on Rakuten.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, I've contacted Udemy and they said that *Unfortunately, Udemy's own API is no longer supported internally, so you can not use it.*

We do have an API that's hosted on Rakuten. You can pull all the following fields for our course catalogue via the feed as well as filter by these items:

courseid

course title

course subtitle

category

subcategory

course url

course image

course description

price (only sending the instructor listing price)

topic

avg rating

course language

num of review

You can find the documentation about our Rakuten API here: https://pubhelp.rakutenmarketing.com/hc/en-us/categories/200082717-Developer-Center-APIs-Data-Feeds

Product Feed Implementation Guide: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18PQ_fPg-g-sN_vMaR8T9tePS_XCP6r0B/view?usp=sharing